# Elasticsearch 5.2 Virtual Memory Issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, memory, lucene

I've locked the memory with mlockall, changed it in systemd but Elasticsearch, and set the memorylock in elasticsearch.yml
Yet somehow still manages to allocate 145 GB of virtual memory. Out of our physical 32 GB of ram, we've allocated 27 GB of it to Elasticsearch alone via jvm.options using -Xmx and -Xms

I don't know what's causing it to allow virtual memory.

We have disabled swapping, we checked our drives and swap wasn't there anymore. We followed everything on the documentation as well.

When we do _nodes?filter_path=**.mlockall it tells us mlockall is true.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which OS are you using? If it is Linux - which kernel version?

Comment: It's running Debian 8 4.x, I don't have access to my server rn sorry